# Python - requests lib - error ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Tags: python, python-requests, twitch

I have an issue with requests lib :
With a code like
`requests.get("HTTPS://api.twitch.tv/helix/...", headers = headers)`,
with the information that twitch API needs in the variable "headers".
And unfortunately, with `except Exception, e:    print(e)` I get `('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))`.
I already tried to fake my user agent.
I'm almost sure that it isn't from server (Twitch) because I also use the ancient API and I have the same bug, while I already used it successfully (Since that, I reseted my Raspberry, it may can explain...).
It doesn't do this error every requests, but like 1 on 10 so it's a bit embarrassing.
I also have this error only with Raspbian, but not with Windows.
Thanks for helping me, a young lost coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons for this error and main of them is - you violate Twitch's user policy (which directly prohibit using scrapers) and server banned some of your requests.

You should try to use sessions when you access site:

`session = requests.Session()`

and use `session.get` instead of `requests.get`

Another things to try are limit your requests rate and rotate different sessions with different headers (don't mix headers and sessions).

Comment: I don't think to be banned, some requests succeed while others not... And it seems to be random... I'll try session thanks for your help ;)

Comment: it seems to be the download process.. but I found a (strange) solution, I just "translated" my code to Python 3, and now it works...